# How to make a test user without a credit card?

Tags: app-store-connect

I'd like to create a test user in iTunes Connect, so I can test in-app purchases. However, iTunes forces me to enter credit card information. Considering this is a test user, for a sandbox environment, that is not supposed to be spending any money, it looks pointless. Is there any way around it? (I know that it is possible to create a *new* account with no payment option, but then it won't be considered as a test user.)

Comment: Thanks for waiting for us to roll out iTunes connect as in-scope for the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, as it turns out the test user can only be used from within the sandbox environment, which makes certain sense. This is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=08282009a).

Comment: This link is no longer helpful, but the test user CANNOT be used on a copy of your app that you downloaded from the App Store (it will ask you to verify the user and enter a credit card). You can use the test user when you are running the app from a build you created in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this today. The answer, in short is:

1. Log OUT in Settings on your iPad, but do **not** log back in to the App Store there
2. Log in from within your app at the moment of making the IAP

Do not enter your credit card info for this sandbox user.